# Centralize in horizontal elements float and if possible, responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble with this question.

I've tried to make all the shapes with the divs stay centered when I reduce the width of the window, but they are following each other, always, and really left (think float: left does).

And images, if possible we would stay responsive interesting to me, but I've tried to control the width percentage and did not work.

Tks for the support.

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5AB/)

```
<div class="general-box">
    <div class="left-right-padding">
        <ul>
            <li class="general-box-title">TITLE 1</li>
            <li> <a id="" href="" title=""><img src="" width="156" height="75" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="left-margin-photo" href="" title=""><img src="" width="101" height="75" alt="" /></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left-right-padding">
        <ul>
            <li class="general-box-title">TITLE 2
                <li> <a href="" title=""><img src="" width="92" height="75" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="left-margin-photo" href="" title=""><img src="" width="160" height="75" alt="" /></a>

                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left-right-padding">
        <ul>
            <li class="general-box-title">TITLE 3
                <li> <a href="" title=""><img src="" width="170" height="75" alt="" /></a>
 <a class="left-margin-photo" href="" title=""><img src="" width="88" height="75" alt="" /></a>

                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    zoom: 1;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
.general-box {
    padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.general-box .left-right-padding {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
.general-box .general-box-title {
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
.general-box .left-margin-photo {
    margin-left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove float, and put

```
.general-box {
    padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.general-box .left-right-padding {
    display: table-cell; 
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

And add a div around the content with this css: display: table and width: 100%

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5AB/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your css. You've got a `float:left` in the class definition which is making all the divs align-left.

```
.general-box {
    padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center /** <-- Add a text-align:center here */
}
.general-box .left-right-padding {
    /** float: left;  <--Remove this */
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5AB/3/)

Comment: Adilapapaya, tks for the support. But I need that the elements remain side by side to initially.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that may work for you is to not `float:left` your `.left-right-padding` box, and instead use the `margin: 0 auto` method.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/8S5AB/4/)**

CSS:

```
.general-box .left-right-padding {
  //float: left;
  //padding: 0 20px 0 20px;

  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Man, tks for the support, but I need that the elements remain side by side to initially and I can't fix a width.